# Dynamically subscribe to Servicebus topics in a not-shared, non-durable way in .Net 7

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, publish-subscribe

I need some help figuring out how to connect a web app pool of varying size, to a servicebus topic in a dynamic way. I am using .Net 7.

The application needs the messages to be received by all currently listening subscribers.

Rather than have to pre-create a bunch of subscriptions that will just waste space when not in use, this would ideally be implemented like in JMS with non-shared, non-durable subscriptions which the client creates on it's own using JMSConsumer.

I would also like to avoid creating a separate service that provisions non-shared, durable subscriptions on demand with some sort of logic to delete unused subscriptions.

I have been looking for a simple way to do this,but the closest I have found is connecting the web app to the administration api of azure to create a durable subscription on the fly granting the app 'Manage' right on the topic. This has two immediate downfalls (outside of being clunky and poor design). This grants more rights than I would like to each of the instances, and also, the apps won't reliably be able to clean up after them selves when the apps are terminated due to scale down, crashes or manual operations.

Anyone have an idea?

Thank you for your help!